# How to crop a video into equal parts with python

Tags: python, video-processing

I am building a python app that needs to crop a video of individual parts based on the given grid. What's the best library for cropping videos?

example: upload a video and split it into a 2x2 grid.

[image]

Comment: ffmpeg can probably be used for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly elegant, but that would do the trick. 
Just a very naive way using open-cv to cut the frame into a grid like frames.
pseudo code: for each frame, split the frame by the grid and save the "chunk" to a list.
when you finish create a mp4 (you can try cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc or what was suggested above ffmpeg) for each list.

```py
import wizzi_utils as wu # pip install wizzi_utils
import cv2


def main():
    video_path = './wizzi_utils_playground/videos/Input/woman_yoga.mp4'
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    if cap.isOpened():
        out_dims = wu.cvt.get_dims_from_cap(cap)
        w, h = out_dims
        total_frames = wu.cvt.get_frames_from_cap(cap)
        print('video {}: frames={}, dims={}'.format(video_path.split('/')[-1], total_frames, out_dims))
        for i in range(total_frames):
            success, frame = cap.read()
            wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(frame, ms=1, title='origFrame({})'.format(frame.shape), loc='top_left')

            # let assume 2x2 grid - you need to write a function that does this in a loop
            chunk_1 = frame[0:int(h / 2), 0:int(w / 2), :]
            wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(chunk_1, ms=1, title='chunk_1({})'.format(chunk_1.shape), loc=(0, 400))

            chunk_2 = frame[0:int(h / 2), int(w / 2):w, :]
            wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(chunk_2, ms=1, title='chunk_2({})'.format(chunk_2.shape), loc=(330, 400))

            chunk_3 = frame[int(h / 2):h, 0:int(w / 2), :]
            wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(chunk_3, ms=1, title='chunk_3({})'.format(chunk_3.shape), loc=(0, 620))

            chunk_4 = frame[int(h / 2):h, int(w / 2):w, :]
            wu.cvt.display_open_cv_image(chunk_4, ms=0, title='chunk_4({})'.format(chunk_4.shape), loc=(330, 620))

            # save each chunk in a different list - finish with 4 lists
            break  # just the first frame for this example

        # create a video from each list
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[see image attached of the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLtHw.png)